# How to fetch the category value once in a while loop with php

Tags: php, sql

This is my code and am using while loop to fetch row values from the database.

```
    <?php
$query = "SELECT I.itemid AS itemid, C.catid AS catid, C.name AS cname, I.name AS iname, I.price As price FROM tbl_item I INNER JOIN tbl_menu_category C ON I.catid=C.catid;"
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>

<ul class="menu-cat" id="menu<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
<li>
<h5><?php echo $row['cname'];?></h5>
<span><?php echo $row['iname'];?></span>
    <span style="float:right"><?php echo $row['iprice'];?></span>
<span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

</li>
  </ul>

   <?php } ?>
```

Everything is working correctly but I want category to appear once as it is showing multiple times.

Example

Category1
Doll 25

Category1 
Car 50

Category2
 Dress 400

Category2 
Gift 100

I want to show as following

Çategory1

Doll 25
Car 50

Çategory2

Dress 400
Gift 100

How will I be able to achieve the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the name of the last category iterated and compare it to the current category. If it's different, print it, if it's not, don't:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT I.itemid AS itemid, C.catid AS catid, C.name AS cname, I.name AS iname, I.price As price FROM tbl_item I INNER JOIN tbl_menu_category C ON I.catid=C.catid;"
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$lastCategory = null;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    ?>
    <ul class="menu-cat" id="menu<?php echo $row['catid'];?>">
        <li>
            <?php if ($lastCategory === null || $lastCategory !== $row["cname"]):?> <h5><?php echo $row['cname'];?></h5><?php endif;?>
            <span><?php echo $row['iname'];?></span>
            <span style="float:right"><?php echo $row['iprice'];?></span>
            <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </li>
        </ul>
    <?php 
    $lastCategory = $row["cname"];
} 
?>
```